# Importer screen stays empty

Tags: windows-7, video, graphics-card, pinnacle-studio

I'm trying to record my old video tapes on my computer, using the Pinnacle Studio 700 PCI Card and Windows 7 Ultimate (SP1, 32 bits).

The PCI card is recognized as Pinnacle AV/DV2 and the most recent drivers are successfully installed:
[image: Besturing voor geluid, video en spelletjes = Sound, video and game controllers]

I'm using Pinnacle Studio 18 (Ultimate, 18.0.2.10342, 32 bit). I've selected the right input channel (S-Video), but no video appears:
 [image: Empty video screen]

I have no clue what's going wrong. I can't find any error messages so I don't know how to look further. What can I do to debug this?

Comment: Is S-video selected as the output on the device you're trying to capture from? If you plug the VCR into a TV via s-video, does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with the VCR. It works as expected on a TV.

Comment: Just for clarification, can you edit in which edition of Windows 7 are you using (Edition and bit-level, ie: Home 32-bit)?  also, which version of Pinnacle Studio is that?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I did!